# NotSerializableException when shutting down glassfish

Tags: jsf-2, glassfish, java-ee-6

I get an `NotSerializableException` when shutting down Glassfish (3.1), due to an `HtmlSelectOneMenu`. I use `HtmlSelectOneMenu` in other controller beans, but they are not bound to the backing bean as this one. This happens only if there are sessions active on the server of course.

How can I avoid exception when starting/stopping Glassfish for the bounded JSF component ?

Controller Class

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
...

public class ActivityController implements Serializable {
    ..
    private DataModel<MyObjcet> items = null;
    private HtmlSelectOneMenu myMenu;
    ...
```

Exception

```
INFO: PWC2785: Cannot serialize session attribute activityController for session a4591e053e65effc743dade67eef
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:2067)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:945)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.writeSessions(StandardManager.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnloadToFile(StandardManager.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5509)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:529)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1049)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2191)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.unloadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2146)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.stop(WebApplication.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.stop(EngineRef.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.stop(ModuleInfo.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.stop(ApplicationInfo.java:314)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:997)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.disable(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1952)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.stopApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:443)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.preDestroy(ApplicationLoaderService.java:411)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorInhabitantImpl.dispose(AbstractCreatorInhabitantImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.release(SingletonInhabitant.java:81)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.release(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:108)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.LazyInhabitant.release(LazyInhabitant.java:133)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.stop(AppServerStartup.java:415)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.stop(GlassFishImpl.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer.doExecute(StopServer.java:70)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopDomainCommand.execute(StopDomainCommand.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:383)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `transient`.

```
private transient HtmlSelectOneMenu myMenu;
```

This way the field will be skipped on (de)serialization. By the way, the `DataModel` is also not serializable.

On the other hand, binding components directly to the backing bean is in most cases a smell. You should consider looking (or asking) for an alternative approach which does not require binding components to the bean.

Comment: I declared them transient for the class that I get exception from (both the HtmlSelectOneMenu and DataModel). But I have several other Controller classes (session scope) that has DataModel that is not transient and I get no exception for these. How can that be ?

Comment: It had apparently no value during serializaiton (i.e. it's `null`). Perhaps the whole field is unused and can thus be safely removed.

Comment: True, they are probably not populated with data yet. Thanks and happy new year!